# SSIS. How to copy data of one table into different tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have one table. It contains 34mln rows. When I tried "INSERT...SELECT..." SQL query via SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO. Now I am trying to copy it using SSIS. How to copy data of table into different other tables?

This is relational schema where I want to divide parts by columns and insert into these tables.
[image]

Comment: "When I tried "INSERT...SELECT..." SQL query via SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO" what do you mean? Did this work or not? For that many rows this will take sometime but will most likely still be faster than SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just briefing, Cerate a SSIS Package. Which flows like follow

- Take Data Flow Task
- Take OLE DB Source and point to Your source table.
- Keep one lookup to restrict already loaded recodrds.(If you execute multiple times)
- Take a OLE DB Destination and point to parent table.
- Take one more Data flow task and point to your source table.
- keep lookup to get ParentTable ID
- Keep one lookup to restrict already loaded recodrds.(If you execute multiple times)
- Take OLE DB for 3 child tables and Load into your child tables.